# Creating D3DX shaders

Tags: c++, directx, shader

Is it possible to create shaders without the use of D3DX functions?

Answer (score 2):

The HLSL compiler is, as of D3D9, part of the D3DX library. To write your shaders in HLSL, you have to use D3DX.

However, there's [`IDirect3DDevice9::CreatePixelShader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`IDirect3DDevice9::CreateVertexShader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174366%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which create a shader handle from shader byte code, that is, from what is generated by the HLSL compiler.

You can run the HLSL compiler offline (see [`D3DXCompileShader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), save  the machine code to a file and load it at runtime using the aforementioned functions. Sadly this means that you cannot rely on the work that is otherwise done by the D3DX framework. Uploading your constants and optimizing changes is totally up to you in this case.

Comment: See [HLSL, FXC, and D3DCompile](https://walbourn.github.io/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile/) which notes you can use the D3DCompile API directly for Shader Model 2.0 or Shader Model 3.0 DX9 shaders.